# Render dynamic # of HTML controls in aspx page like @Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know we can put a placehold on aspx page, then add controls dynamically from backend code. Is there a way in aspx page that is similar to @razor engine that we can add html control directly in aspx page?

```
<% 
    int count = GetImageCount();
    for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
    {
        string id = "img_" + k.ToString();
%>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" />

<%                    
    }                   
%>
```

We can use above code to add multiple Image control in aspx page, but how can we set them with different id and src?

Or, we can not do this in aspx directly?

thanks

Comment: you want a server control `<asp:Image`>? if you use simple `img` tag then you can set all attributes to it like in razor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set ID for server controls dynamically. Also, as far as I am aware of, setting ImageUrl direclty in aspx for the control in for loop, like in your code, might not be possible - you should probably take a look and `asp:Repeater` control.

To achieve what you want, you might find useful this piece of code, using HTML `<img>` control (as @Grundy suggested), instead of `asp:Image` control:

```
<% int count = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        string id = "id_" + i;
        string imageUrl = "/Images/img_" + i;
%>
    <img id="<%=id%>" src="<%=imageUrl%>"/>
<% 
    }
%>
```

Comment: thanks. I knew miss something simple, did not notice I use the asp server control. I actually want to use html control, :)